# Remove Background image opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Please hold before downgrading the Question. I am not looking for a segmentation or detection algorithm/library.

I have also seen this Post

[Remove background of the image using opencv Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294109/remove-background-of-the-image-using-opencv-python)

But the solution marked correct is again what I don't want. I want exactly

What are the ways to Subtract the BACKGROUND image from FOREGROUND?

Input:

1. Background Image without vehicle like the above post
2. Foreground Image with the vehicle

Output:

1. Vehicle

Be kind and thanks for the help.

**Link to the Input Images** [Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kocnJ.jpg)

**Link to the Output** [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXgye.jpg)

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. What's specifically wrong with the result of the accepted answer? Please attach an image of YOUR desired output. maybe manually drawn.

Comment: updated Question, I must process the background image with the foreground image and get output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove background of the image using opencv Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294109/remove-background-of-the-image-using-opencv-python)

Comment: voted to close because your question is the same, and you made no distinction even though you were asked to. Please state what is different about your question, and attach required output (which is different, or this is a duplicate)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789446/11803249) answers you question?

Comment: Or perhaps this will help: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html

Comment: @Gulzar The same Question I mentioned that It doesn't work according to my requirements

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei dear this one is really bad considering Speed. I left because of Speed limitation.

Comment: @beaker No this one also didn't work but yes helped me in searching

Comment: @user7657688 how are your requirements different?

Comment: @Gulzar the problem is I tried with backgroundSubtractorKNN it didn't work but MOG works because MOG takes multiple frames to learn rather than single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV background Subtractor models [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html)

After a lot of testing, Videos based MOG/MOG2 works better than single Image based background subtraction with KNN.

This [article](https://medium.com/swlh/roi-segmentation-contour-detection-and-image-thresholding-using-opencv-c0d2ea47b787) solved my problem